# Simple game throws StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I made this simple game where an image is drawn where the cursor is. For a while it works but soon it throws a StackOverFlowError Exception.

```
public class Graphic extends JComponent {
private ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/Koolkids/Documents/codeStuff/Java/BattleOfTheEmojis/src/img/happy.png");
private Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
private Point cursor = new Point(0, 0);

public MouseMotionAdapter m = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseMoved(e);
        cursor = e.getPoint();
    }
};



public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    this.addMouseMotionListener(m);
    g2.drawImage(img, cursor.x - 11, cursor.y - 11, 22, 23, this);
    repaint();

}

}
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:329)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:329)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:329)
```

and continues like that forever.

Comment: Not experienced with Java UI code, but - it looks like you're adding a new event listener every single frame by calling `this.addMouseMotionListener(m);` in your paint function.

Comment: and also remove that `super.mouseMoved(e);`

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `repaint` nor add the listener inside the `paint` method.

The `paint` method is called by Swing every time the component needs to be updated/drawn The `repaint` method schedules the component for redrawing, which causes `paint` to be called. So calling `repaint` inside of `paint` is kind of an endless loop.

The listener should be added only once to the component, e.g. when the component is created.

`repaint` should be called when the representation of the component was changed, e.g. inside the listener after changing `cursor`.